# Goodness-of-fit algorithms for comparing different simulation approaches

Tags: goodness-of-fit, monte-carlo

I want to compare sample generating algorithms against trusted Monte-Carlo simulations for goodness of fit. I would like an algorithm that takes samples one at a time or in batch from both the Monte-Carlo and the algorithm I am testing and computes a goodness of fit.

Most of the algorithms I have found test to want a CDF or compare the samples against themselves. For example, the [Anderson-Darling test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson.html#scipy.stats.anderson), the [k-sample AD test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html#scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp), and [the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html). I would like to compare my samples against my Monto-Carlo simulation because the CDF is hard to compute because it is high dimensional.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you testing goodness-of-fit for a multivariate distribution?

Comment: @jbowman Yes. The p.d.f. is over a multi-dimensional Riemannian manifold with a non-trivial metric.